# implementing ajax call in fullcalendar using php

Tags: php, ajax, fullcalendar, pyrocms

I have already implemented full calenedar in php. It works fine . I have called the data from database and shown it in the fullcalendar.
Now I have implemented a dropdown. I have used ajax to call controller that calls my another view.
The controller fetches the data based on the dropdown selection. By default it fetches all the data.
But i am not getting the calendar after ajax call. I have called the script to load full calendar in ajax view. 
When I echo in the ajax view page, i get the required data. But I am not able to display the full calendar after the ajax call.

As suggested i have give the code.

My first view:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/drive_training/addons/shared_addons/modules/schedule/css/fullcalendar.print.css" rel="stylesheet" media="print" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/drive_training/addons/shared_addons/modules/schedule/css/fullcalendar.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="content">
    <div id='input'>
        <?php echo form_dropdown("package_id", $packagelist, "",'id="packageid"'); ?>
    </div>
    <div id='calendar'></div>
</div>

<style>
    #calendar {
        max-width: 900px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#packageid').change(function() { //any select change on the dropdown with id country trigger this code           
            var packageid = $('#packageid').val();
           alert(packageid);

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "<?php echo base_url('admin/schedule/scheduledetails/hel') ?>", //here we are calling our user controller and get_cities method with the country_id
                data: {'packageid': packageid,},
                success: function(data)
                {  


                },
                error: function() {
                    alert('failed');
                }
            });



        });
    });

</script>

<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {       

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
            },
            displayEventEnd: {
                month: true,
                basicWeek: true,
                "default": true
            },
            defaultDate: '2014-11-12',
            //editable: true,
            eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events

            events: 
            "<?php echo base_url('admin/schedule/scheduledetails/json');?>",
        });

    });

</script>
```

My controller hel function

```
 public function hel()
{ 
    $packageid = 9;//$_POST['packageid']; 

//   echo "hello";
   $coursedetails = $this->course_m->where('course_id',$packageid)->get_all();
  // echo "<pre>";print_r($coursedetails); echo "</pre>";
    $scheduledetails = array();
        foreach ($coursedetails as $details) {

            $packagedays = $this->course_m->packagedays($details->id);
            $presentdays = $this->attendance_m->count_attendance($details->id);

            $startdate = $details->start_date;
            $starttime = $details->start_time;
            $endtime = $details->end_time;
            $postponedays = 0;
            //$enddate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($details->start_date . ' + ' . $packagedays . ' days'));

            $postponedays = $this->postpone_m->count_postponedays($details->id);
            if ($postponedays == 0) {
                $enddate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($details->start_date . ' + ' . $packagedays . ' days'));
            } else {
                $add = $postponedays + $packagedays;
                $enddate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($details->start_date . ' + ' . $add . ' days'));
                $postponefrom = $this->postpone_m->postponedate($details->id)->postponefrom;
                $postponeto = $this->postpone_m->postponedate($details->id)->postponeto;
                //echo $postponeto;die;
            }

            $temp = array
                (
                array
                    (
                    'course_id' => $details->id, //it means acutal course id
                    'title' => $this->training_package_m->get($details->course_id)->training_code, //course_id means packageid                    
                    'start' => $startdate . 'T' . $starttime,
                    'end' => $enddate . 'T' . $endtime,
                    'description' => 'Hello gyys how are you all',
                    'starttime' => $starttime,
                    'endtime' => $endtime,
                   // 'postponefrom' => $postponefrom,
                    //'postponeto' => $postponeto,
                    'postponeddays' => $postponedays,
                    'packagedays' => $packagedays,                
                    ),
                );
            $scheduledetails = array_merge($scheduledetails, $temp);
        }
        // echo json_encode($scheduledetails); 

          $data['jsondata'] = json_encode($scheduledetails);

          //print_r($data['jsondata']);die;
           $this->template
               ->title($this->module_details['name'])                
                ->set_layout(false)
                ->build('admin/fullcalendarfiltered',$data);             


}
```

My view to load through controller. i.e fullcalendarfiltered view file

```
<style>
    #calendar {
        max-width: 900px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
</style> 
<div>Test Ajax</div>
 <div id='calendar'></div>
<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {       

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
            },
            displayEventEnd: {
                month: true,
                basicWeek: true,
                "default": true
            },
            defaultDate: '2014-11-22',
            //editable: true,
            eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events

            events: "<?= $jsondata?>",
        });

    });
</script>
```

The view file displays test ajax only. when i echo the json data in view file it is echoed. But the problem is that it wont load in calendar. Infact the calendar is not displayed in fullcalendarfiltered view file

Comment: Just ask yourself how can people answer without any code?

Comment: Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Mihai so you want to see the code then be it. I will post the code and wait if you could help